# Relevance of upper vs lower sum indices

Tags: summation

I read [this related thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35080/upper-limit-of-summation-index-lower-than-lower-limit) but it doesn't give me a satisfactory answer to the following question:

Must it be true that the order of indices in a sum is relevant?  A finite sum is essentially adding up all elements in a set.  Who cares it that set is ordered forwards or backwards?  Consider the following examples.

Common convention tells us that

$$\sum_{n=5}^0n=0$$

even though we are essentially trying to add the elements of {$n\in[0,5]$} backwards.  The validity of this becomes paramount in the following case,

$$\sum_{m=0}^n f(n-m)\ne0$$

when we make a simplifying change of variable $m=n-i$.  Then, the sum becomes

$$\sum_{i=n}^0 f(i)=0, \text{by convention.}$$

Obviously nothing significant has changed with the sum when we just change a variable definition, Why, then, does the convention dictate that the value of the sum must change?  It seems this particular sum convention is nonsense and should be abandoned.

Comment: Since $i$ appears with a minus sign, the limits should be switched (like in integrals).

Comment: @egreg What do you mean $i$ appears with a sign?   $m=n-i$ means $m=0$ maps to $n=i$ as the lower index.

Comment: You have $n\color{red}{-}i$. Such a transformation reverses the order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write the summation as
$$
\sum_{0\le m\le n}f(n-m)
$$
and do the substitution $m=n-i$, then the condition in the sum becomes
$$
0\le n-i\le n
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
n\ge i\ge 0
$$
which in turn can be written as $0\le i\le n$.

Therefore
$$
\sum_{0\le m\le n}f(n-m)=\sum_{0\le i\le n}f(i)
$$

---

A summation such as
$$
\sum_{n=5}^0 f(n)
$$
can (should?) be written as
$$
\sum_{5\le n\le0}f(n)
$$
and no index $n$ satisfies the condition, so the summation is by definition $0$.

Comment: Thanks, the sum notation in hindsight makes much more sense when written as such an inequality.

Comment: @avikarto Yes, that's why I always prefer using inequalities in my notes.